# border not display in my images

Tags: java, android, border

my gallery display my images but which image select i don't know how to differentiate selected image and other images.. i want to set border line in my image...now i am attach my screen shots help me....

my screenshot:
[image]

i expect this type of screen in my emulator:
[image]

```
package videothumb.videothumb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.graphics.Color;

public class videothumb extends Activity{

private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI =    
MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
//flag for which one is used for images selection
private Gallery _gallery; 
private Cursor _cursor;
private int _columnIndex;
private int[] _videosId;
private Uri _contentUri;
private int video_column_index;

//private static final int MENU_ID_ZOOM = 0;


protected Context _context;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    _context = getApplicationContext();

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    //set GridView for gallery
    _gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.videoGrdVw);
    //set default as external/sdcard uri
    _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //initialize the videos uri 
    //showToast(_contentUri.getPath());
    initVideosId();
    //set gallery adapter
     setGalleryAdapter();
   }
private void setGalleryAdapter() {
    _gallery.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(_context));
    _gallery.setOnItemClickListener(videogridlistener);
    }
private void initVideosId() {
    try
    {
        //Here we set up a string array of the thumbnail ID column we want to get back
        String [] proj={_ID};
        // Now we create the cursor pointing to the external thumbnail store
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int count= _cursor.getCount();
        System.out.println("total"+_cursor.getCount());
        // We now get the column index of the thumbnail id
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
        //initialize 
        _videosId = new int[count];
        //move position to first element
        _cursor.moveToFirst();            
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {            
            int id = _cursor.getInt(_columnIndex);
            //

            _videosId[i]= id;
            //
            _cursor.moveToNext();
            //
        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        showToast(ex.getMessage().toString());            
    }

    }
   protected void showToast(String msg)
   {
     Toast.makeText(_context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   private OnItemClickListener videogridlistener = new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
    long id) {
        // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
        String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
        // We request our cursor again
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null);
          //System.gc();
         // video_column_index =    
                           _cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
          _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);
            // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
            _cursor.moveToPosition(position);

          String filename = _cursor.getString(_columnIndex);
          Intent intent = new Intent(videothumb.this, ViewVideo.class);
          intent.putExtra("videofilename", filename);
          startActivity(intent);
          showToast(filename);
         // Toast.makeText(videothumb.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
       };
    private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
    public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        _context = c;

    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return _videosId.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);
        try
        {
            if(convertView!=null)
            {
                imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(_videosId[position]));
            imgVw.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            //imgVw.draw(canvas);
            //imgVw.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            imgVw.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
            imgVw.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("StartActivity:getView()-135: ex " + ex.getClass() +", 
          "+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        return imgVw;
    }

    // Create the thumbnail on the fly
    private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
    Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(getContentResolver(),id, 
    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
      System.out.println("ff"+MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail
     (getContentResolver(),
     id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null));
        return thumb;
    }

     }

          }
```

[image]

i am set background color....

Comment: what have you already tried to set a border to image?

Comment: no how to set border in image...i dont know i am new for android.. can u tell me....

Comment: give me your suggestion....please....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the background color of the ImageView same as the border color. And set padding of the imageview to the size of the border. It will work for what you want.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 
 
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="#FFCCCCCC" android:src="@drawable/header" android:padding="5dip"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
In the src you have to give your own image

Comment: ok but i create image view directly in java file...(ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);)i am not using xml file... if make any mistake tell me. now i am post my full coding few mint..

Comment: ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);
        try
        {
            if(convertView!=null)
            {
                imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(_videosId[position]));
            imgVw.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            //imgVw.draw(canvas);
            
            imgVw.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(150, 100));
      imgVw.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);      imgVw.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        }

Comment: ok...its working fine... but its display background color...but i need border color when i switch one image to another image the border also to change that type i am expected...

Comment: for this you have to change the background color when you select an imageview.

Comment: ok another one doubt my textview is display in top of the screen how to change the bottom...